# java google app engine get entity by key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, entity, jdo

I have a problem using GAEJ and JDO for storing the data.
This is what I'm working with:

class Usuari.java:

```
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key key;

@Persistent
private String email;

@Persistent
private String rol="";
```

class DBUtils.java: 
I've tried with two ways of doing the delete operation:

```
// This method removes a record from the database using its unique Key
public static boolean eliminar(Key k) throws Exception {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    String kind;
    Long id;
    kind = k.getKind();
    id = k.getId();
    try {
        if (k.getKind().equals("Usuari")) {
            Usuari u = (Usuari)pm.getObjectById(k);
            pm.deletePersistent(u);
            _log.log(Level.INFO, "Deleted an entity->kind: " + kind + " id: " + id);
        }

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to delete an entity->kind: " + kind + " id: " + id);
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
    finally {
        pm.close();
    }
}

// This method removes a record from the database using its unique Key - too
public static void eliminar2(Key k) throws Exception {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    javax.jdo.Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try
    {
        tx.begin();
        if (k.getKind().equals("Usuari")) {
            Usuari u = (Usuari) pm.getObjectById(k);
            pm.deletePersistent(u);
        }
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (tx.isActive())
        {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I'm able to create new instances of some class "Usuari" but I can't delete them.
Everytime I call "eliminar" or "eliminar2" methods I get a "No such object" as result of trying to fetch it. I've checked manually and I see the object exists in my admin panel, with its ID and KIND, so I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PM.getObjectById` does not take in a `Key` object, as per the JDO spec. It takes in an *identity* object, the same type as you would get from `pm.getObjectId(obj)`; suggest you glance through the JDO spec. No doubt if you inspected what is returned from this method you would see that it can't find an object with that 'identity' because a Key is not an identity. You can also do

```
pm.getObjectById(Usuari.class, key);
```

which is shown very clearly in GAE documentation.

Still don't get why users are putting @Persistent on every field virtually every type is default persistent; only leads to making code more unreadable.

Comment: Hi DataNucleous, thank you very much for taking your time to answer me.

I’ve read a lot of times GAEJ’s documentation: all I know is thanks of it and a lot of answered questions I've read here.

I want to use this method to have a “template” delete method, so I thought passing the Key object would be enough and would let me delete any kind of Entity.
Your solution did work perfectly.
 
Now, in your opinion, what's better: having one delete method for each kind of Entity or only one delete method and have a switch-case inside and with Key's getKind() method know the entity's class to delete?

Comment: About putting @Persistent in every field, I do it because I've seen it in almost every tutorial I've read. I didn't know it wasn't necessary, I won't put it from now on.